# Transaction taking forever

Tags: gas

I sent yesterday a couple of transactions from IDEX to myetherwallet, they are accepted and being mined. However, it was the 1st time I used it and I think I set up a very low gas price (12, the one suggested by IDEX), and over 5M blocks only 5000 have been mined in 8 hours.

Is there a way to cancel it and resend it with more gas? If I go to IDEX I actually see that amount of tokens on myetherwallet so maybe I could make a deposit again on IDEX and send it back again?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share the transaction hashes for the transactions in question? There are a lot of confusing statements in your question.

Comment: Sure: 0xfafd525c9e450104f2dda375749911a4af3bae0be023e9239a0b146f2c6bf8fd

Comment: That transaction succeeded 9 hours ago.

Comment: The weird thing is my balance on MEW hasn’t changed, I can only see my tokens on IDEX